# Output buffer is putting html tags in the end of the file

Tags: php, html, output-buffering

I want user to be able to download a file which is generated on the fly ( not stored at the server).

In order to do so I created `test case` simple website with `form` and a `submit` button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Some Test tittle</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<div>
<div>
<form action='/thispage.php' method='post' class='asholder' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='submit' value='Generate' name='generatetxt'>
</form>
</div>

</div>

<div id='bottom-bar'></div>

</html>
```

Then I have created condition to execute `createTxt` method everytime when in `$_POST` will be `generatetxt` field:

```
if (in_array('generatetxt',$_POST)){
    ob_end_clean();
    createTxt("some other text");
    ob_flush(); 
}
```

and the `createTxt` function

```
function createTxt($profile){
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.txt"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    echo "SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOMTE TEXT SOME TEXT\n";
    echo $profile;
}
```

However everytime user is downloading `.txt` file he gets something like:

```
SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOMTE TEXT SOME TEXT
some other text
</div>

</div>

<div id='bottom-bar'></div>

</html>
```

Can anyone give me a hint how I can use output buffer to remove `html tags` from the downloaded file content?

Comment: Not possible without seeing the complete code of that page "thispage.php"

Comment: I suggest using `header("Content-Type:text/plain");` instead of application/octet-stream

Comment: M.Franz thispage.php is the exacly same page i showed . Callback in the `action` field is to the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for output buffering. You can strip html tags off from `$profile` when `echo`ing it (using [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) function)

```
echo strip_tags($profile);
```

Also do not forget to have an `exit` call after you output txt content.

```
createTxt($profile);
exit;
```

Comment: I $profile is a string I have edited the question. Problem is that there are clearly tags which are outside the <form> tag displayed in the file

Comment: sorry, could not understand the edit. $profile was already a string??

Comment: Yes. Im sorry for the confusing You ;/

Comment: sorry, could not understand. did this fix your problem?

Comment: It is actually funny thing. I have tested it only by adding `exit;` and it works. Isn't it like using `break;` considered as bad habbit?

Comment: yes, generally exit; break; statements are antipatterns. But for this case, you need to exit because your code does not have a separate path for file creation. After you check&create file in if block, flow continues and you apparently had some other output after this if block.